# MongoDB Wildcard database security for a user account

Tags: mongodb

I need to create a mongodb user (v7) that needs to be the dbowner for multiple databases. I would like for them to be able to create databases without giving them a "root" role and locking to into only being able to control the databases they create. Our application separates tenants by databases and creates the databases on the fly.

Is it possible to give them the ability to create/own databases that start with a certain string?

For example, UserABC would be able to create/own any database that started with "ABC" (like ABC_Client1, ABC_Client2, ...) but if there were other databases like "XYZ..." they would not have access or be able to do anything with those.

I know this isn't the correct role/setup but to try an illustrate what I am asking. The "*" doesn't work for dbOwner (just creates a db with a * in the name) and it didn't seem that a $regex would work either. The second "role" I assume I would need some sort of "create database" permission for the user along with a way to specify a wild card for the database name.

```
use admin;
db.grantRolesToUser(
   "UserABC",
   [ { role: "dbOwner", db: "ABC*" }, { role: 'create?!?', db: "ABC*" } ]
)
```

Right now, we run on a dedicated MongoDB instance per application environment with the service account in each environment having the root role but would like to tighten the security around the service account and also be able to consolidate instances to cut costs if at all possible.

Comment: You may review your application design. Why do you want users to create their own databases?

Comment: It automates our onboarding processing … we just send a link to a web form, they fill in the information required, a script runs and creates their database and collections … would like to limit the service account incase of a data breach it would only affect the single application’s group of databases and not all databases on the mongo db instance

Comment: When you say "a script runs" then where is your problem? Just add the command to this script which grants `dbOwner` privilege for the new database to the user.